# Loggers and java.lang.SecurityManager

Tags: java, logging, code-access-security

I understand that java.lang.SecurityManager is used to check and constrain class access or file access based on a specific scenario.

I need to identify the caller for Log4J Helper class which needs to return the Logger instance based on Class which calls the Helper class.

There are two ways to do this.

**Using Threads**

```java
public static Logger getLogger() {
    final Throwable thread = new Throwable();
    final StackTraceElement callerMethod = thread .getStackTrace()[1];
    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(callerMethod .getClassName());
    return logger;
}
```

This is a performance bottleneck since it involves get the current stacktrace for each call to getLogger

**Second Approach**

Logging helper to extend java.lang.SecurityManager in which case i can use

```
getClassContext()[2].getName();
```

to get the absolute class name for instantiating the Logger.

The LoggingHelper extending the SecurityManager doesn't seem to be a good design principle considering its usage.

Would there any be any reason i can extend SecurityManager to a Logging Utility or is there a better approach?

Note : The application will be running in app server instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java EE 6 you could use CDI to inject your logger.

```java
public class LoggerProducer {

    @Produces 
    public Log createLogger(final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        final String name = injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName(); 
        return Logger.getLogger(name);
    }
}
```